# Another double type trick in C++?

Tags: c++, double

First, I understand that the double type in C++ has been discussed lots of time, but I wasn't able to answer my question after searching. Any help or idea is highly appreciated.

**The simplified version of my question is:** I got three different results (`a=-0.926909`, `a=-0.926947` and `a=-0.926862`) when I computed `a=b-c+d` with three different approaches and the same values of `b`, `c` and `d`, and I don't know which one to trust.

**The detailed version of my question is:**

I was recently writing a program (in C++ on Ubuntu 10.10) to handle some data. One function looks like this:

```
void calc() {
   double a, b;
   ...
   a = b - c + d; // c, d are global variables of double
   ...
}
```

When I was using GDB to debug the above code, during a call to calc(), I recorded the values of `b`, `c` and `d` before the statement `a = b - c + d` as follows:

```
b = 54.7231
c = 55.4051
d = -0.244947
```

After the statement `a = b - c + d` excuted, I found that `a=-0.926909` instead of `-0.926947` which is calculated by a calculator. Well, so far it is not quite confusing yet, as I guess this might just be a precision problem. Later on I re-implemented another version of `calc()` for some reason. Let's call this new version `calc_new()`. `calc_new()` is almost the same as `calc()`, except for how and where `b`, `c` and `d` are calculated:

```
void calc_new() {
   double a, b;
   ...
   a = b - c + d; // c, d are global variables of double
   ...
}
```

This time when I was debugging, the values of `b`, `c` and `d` before the statement `a = b - c + d` are the same as when `calc()` was debugged: `b = 54.7231`, `c = 55.4051`,  `d = -0.244947`. However, this time after the statement `a = b - c + d` executed, I got `a=-0.926862`. That being said, I got three different `a` when I computed `a = b - c + d` with the same values of `b`, `c` and `d`. I think differences between `a=-0.926862`, `a=-0.926909` and `a=-0.926947` are not small, but I cannot figure out the cause. And which one is correct?

With Many Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Please format your code next time.

Comment: It's not possible, there should be something different (or global variables have been changed). Same operation with same inputs (with the same data type) MUST return the same value (-0,926947).

Comment: Are those the exact values of the variables (as far as the precision of `double` allows)? Or the values displayed in your debugger, which probably only displays the first few significant figures?

Comment: @Adriano I'm not sure about C++, but the C standard explicitly contradicts your claim (look for `FP_CONTRACT`, for example), and I suspect C++ has similar rules.

Comment: Adriano: Thanks for the hint. But I had double-checked that the values of b, c and d are the same (by printing to std output and by watching them in a GDB session) before a=b-c+d executed, in either calc() or calc_new(). The program is single-threaded, and there are no other threads modifying b, c and d when calc() or calc_new() is called.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your description of how `calc_new()` differs from `calc()`. The code you've posted looks exactly the same. Can you provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @Adriano: this is only correct if they are executed in the same order and are loaded into registers the same way. For example, if `b` is the result of some computation recently done it may be in a register and contain a slightly different value than it would have when loaded from memory.

Comment: To Mike Seymour: I actually had the same concern as yours. But the values I printed to (using `cout`) the screen are the same as the ones I saw in my debugger.

Comment: @TomZ: How many digits did you compare? From what you showed the difference happens to be about the order of precision you printed but `double` contains I think 15 decimal digits (of course, this doesn't mean that computations are precise to 15 decimal digits). To pin-point where the problem is it would also be necessary to see how things are actually different.

Comment: @TomZ: by default streams are set up to print 6 significant digits. There are more digits and to show them you'd need to increase the precision, e.g. using `std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10);`

Comment: Please show that actual code that initializes the variables and performs the calculation (including any intermediate calculations used). There shouldn't be such a wild variation in such a simple expression with the values you've posted.

Comment: @hvd it can be used in C++ too but it doesn't affect (if **not changed**) the assertion. If ON the same function will always return the same value. If OFF the same function will always return the same value. If changed then the result _may_ be different. Moreover it's not implemented in every compiler/architecture. **If his function can return different values based on weather then he produced a possibly great random numbers generator**!!!

Comment: @Dietmar it's NOT possible! If in programming in C you get different values from a function then you have a bug in your compiler, in your processor or a memory issue (of course, single threaded environment and other stuffs like that, I don't want to write something obvious). SAME CODE **MUST** PRODUCE THE SAME RESULT. ALWAYS. FOREVER.

Comment: @Adriano No, that's just plain wrong. Read about `FP_CONTRACT` again: if enabled, operations **may** be contracted. Whether they actually are depends on a number of factors, and the result will depend on whether the contraction has taken place.

Comment: @Adriano Not to mention that the C standard (and again presumably C++) allows intermediate results to be carried out in higher precision, or rounded to the static type, again based on other factors than the code you wrote.

Comment: @hvd **may** be contracted if the current target architecture supports them; If the expression is _compatible_ with them. But both conditions doesn't change during program execution. We're talking about numbers, they can't change in this way!

Comment: @Adriano If the expression is contractable, and `FP_CONTRACT` is enabled, the standard does not require the expression to be contracted. If, for whatever reason, the hardware can evaluate `b - c + d` as a single operation but it's easier not to, for example because `b - c` has already been calculated for other reasons, then it doesn't need to be contracted.

Comment: @hvd I can't agree. Same inputs must produce the same output (if boundary conditions) doesn't change. It's a corner brick of informatic. If for __any reason__ a contracted expression can't produce a right result then the **compiler** won't use them at all for that expression. He didn't write assembly code.

Comment: @Adriano For the third time, **read** about `FP_CONTRACT` already. The standard rather explicitly permits floating-point contraction to generate different results than the non-contracted operation.

Comment: @Adriano All you've been doing so far is shouting I'm wrong. Try backing it up with some arguments based on an authoritative source already. Otherwise, I'm done with you here.

Comment: @Adriano: you are right: identical code with identical inputs has to produce identical results. However, the code isn't identical according to the original author. In that case, it isn't required to produce identical results and there are lots of subtle reasons why identical expressions yield different results if the surrounding context is different. For example, it can matter that one variable is read from a global value compared to using a result of a computation passed as argument to a function even though the global was also assigned this result.

Comment: @hvd yes, it's called Turing Machine...

Comment: @DietmarKühl You're right. In my first comment I was trying to move the point on that (citation: It's not possible, there should be something different, or global variables have been changed).

Comment: I assumed some trick question, with the numbers that the OP gave being different numbers, rounded to the same value. It turned out that it was a trick question, although unintentional. Therefore voted down. (Other possibilities: A #define double float hidden somewhere and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rational numbers do not always have a terminating expansion in a given base.  1/3rd cannot be expressed in a finite number of digits in base ten.  In base 2, rational numbers with a denominator that is a power of two will have a terminating expansion.  The rest won't.  So 1/2, 1/4, 3/8, 7/16.... any number that looks like x/(2^n) can be represented accurately.  That turns out to be a fairly sparse subset of the infinite series of rational numbers.  Everything else will be subject to the errors introduced by trying to represent an infinite number of binary digits within a finite container.

But addition is commutative, right?  Yes.  But when you start introducing rounding errors things change a little.  With a = b + c + d as an example, let's say that d cannot be expressed in a finite number of binary digits.  Neither can c.  So adding them together will give us some inaccurate value, which itself may also be incapable of being represented in a finite number of binary digits.  So error on top of error.  Then we add that value to b, which may also not be a terminating expansion in binary.  So taking one inaccurate result and adding it to another inaccurate number results in another inaccurate number.  And because we're throwing away precision at every step, we potentially break the symmetry of commutativity at each step.

There's a post I made: (Perl-related, but it's a universal topic) [Re: Shocking Imprecision (PerlMonks)](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=932033), and of course the canonical [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Math](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), both which discuss the topic.  The latter is far more detailed.

Comment: But if he execute "a = b + c + d" ten times it must always get the same result, doesn't matter WHERE it computes that. Numbers aren't rounded in a different way...

Comment: It seems I was deceived by the output of the debugger and the `cout` function. I compiled my code with M$ Visual Studio and debugged the program again. This time, I noticed in the VS debugger that `b`, `c` and `d` are slightly different in `calc()` and `calc_new()`.

Comment: BTW, I am debugging my code with VS on 64-bit Win 7, and the old code with gdb on 32-bit Ubuntu. Not sure if this makes difference.

Comment: @Tom Z If this is not the answer then kindly un-accept it. :)  Good information though it may be, if it's not applicable in this situation there's no point keeping it around.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect the answer to be accurate in the 5th and 6th decimal place, you need to know exactly what the inputs to the calculation are in those places. You are seeing inputs with only 4 decimal places, you need to display their 5th and 6th place as well. Then I think you would see a comprehensible situation that matches your calculator to 6 decimal places. Double has more than sufficient precision for this job, there would only be precision problems here if you were taking the difference of two very similar numbers (you're not).

Edit: Unsurprisingly, increasing the display precision would have also shown you that calc() and calc_new() were supplying different inputs to the calculation. Credit to Mike Seymour and Dietmar Kuhl in the comments who were the first to see your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer the question I suspect that you meant to ask.  If I have mistaken your intent, then you can disregard the answer.

Suppose that I have the numbers *u = 500.1* and *v = 5.001,* each to four decimal places of accuracy.  What then is *w = u + v*?  Answer, *w = 505.101,* but to four decimal places, it's *w = 505.1.*

Now consider *x = w - u = 5.000,* which should equal *v,* but doesn't quite.

If I only change the order of operations however, I can get *x* to equal *v* exactly, not by *x = w - u* or by *x = (u + v) - u,* but by *x = v + (u - u).*

Is that trivial?  Yes, in my example, it is; but the same principle applies in your example, except that they aren't really decimal places but bits of precision.

In general, to maintain precision, if you have some floating-point numbers to sum, you should try to add the small ones together first, and only bring the larger ones into the sum later.

Answer (score 1):

We're discussing here about *smoke*. If nothing changed in the environment an expression like:

```
a = b + c + d
```

**MUST ALWAYS RETURN THE SAME VALUE IF INPUTS AREN'T CHANGED**.

No rounding errors. No esoteric pragmas, nothing at all.

If you check your bank account today and tomorrow (and nothing changed in that time) I suspect you'll go crazy if you see something different. We're speaking about programs, not random number generators!!!

Comment: Your bank hopefully won't be storing any amount of money in a binary floating-point format.

Comment: You're right but my car does. The airplane we take for holidays. Its GPS and so on...

Comment: Unfortunately;
a) the inputs were changed
b) he didn't know what the inputs were to correct precision

Comment: @DavidO It's wrong, and even if it were right, not the answer to the question, so no, it shouldn't be accepted.

Comment: @BillForster that's the point. Inputs changed, discussion was going on about rounding errors... :|

Comment: That's my point here too: @Adriano correctly identified that if inputs didn't change, result shouldn't change.  OP then went on to discover that, sure enough, inputs changed.  My answer (that currently is accepted) answers the wrong question, and shouldn't be accepted.  Perhaps it provided interesting information, but mine has the checkmark and shouldn't.

Comment: Guys, I hope we're discussing about code and floating point arithmetic not about a votes and which answer should be marked as accepted (to read as: if @TomZ understood his problem reading your answer then it's right he accepted it).

Answer (score 1):

The correct one is -0.926947.

The differences you see are far too large for rounding errors (even in single precision) as one can check in [this encoder](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/).
When using the encoder, you need to enter them like this: -55.926909 (to account for the potential effect of the operator commutativity effects nicely described in previously submitted answers.)  Additionally, a difference in just the last significant bit may well be due to rounding effects, but you will not see any with your values.

When using the tool, 64bit format (Binary64) corresponds to your implementation's double type.